# Calculating division of unique pairs for each row in a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, division

Here I have a 5*4 matrix (much larger originally). I would like to calculate the ratios for each unique pair in each row of a matrix.

```
X1  X2  X3  X4
10  8   2   1
4   4   3   6
2   10  8   1
1   2   1   10
3   5   5   4
```

I would like to achieve a 5*6 matrix with non repeating divisions, like the following >

```
x1/x2   x1/x3   x1/x4   x2/x3   x2x4    x3/x4
1.25    5.00    10.00   4.00    8.00    2.00
1.00    1.33    0.67    1.33    0.67    0.50
0.20    0.25    2.00    1.25    10.00   8.00
0.50    1.00    0.10    2.00    0.20    0.10
0.60    0.60    0.75    1.00    1.25    1.25
```

For now I have created a functions that I hoped would do the trick, however the outcome is not as expected.

```
set.seed(7)
test <- data.frame(replicate(4,sample(1:10,5,rep=TRUE)))

func_calcRatio <- function(theMatrix){

  ratios <- outer(theMatrix, theMatrix, '/')
  ratios <- ratios[upper.tri(ratios)]
  return(ratios)
}


func_ratioMatrix <- function(theMatrix){

  ratios_list <- list()
  i = 1
  l = length(theMatrix)
  for (i in 1:l) {
    vec <- numeric(l)
    for (j in 1:l){
      vec[j] <- i^j
    }
    myrow <- theMatrix[,1]
    onerow <- func_calcRatio(myrow)
    ratios_list[[i]] <- onerow
    i = i+1
  }

  ratios_df <- do.call("rbind", ratios_list)
  return(ratios_df)
}

test.ratios <-  func_ratioMatrix(test)
```

Comment: Note that from the printed output this looks a lot like a data.frame rather than a matrix. It is an important distinction in R, as often times different solutions are used for these different object types. You can tell the object type in this instance using `class(objectName)`.

Answer (score 3):

let the matrix above be `A`. then you can use the code below:

```
    combn(4,2,function(x) A[,x[1]]/A[,x[2]])
       [,1]     [,2]       [,3]     [,4]       [,5] [,6]
  [1,] 1.25 5.000000 10.0000000 4.000000  8.0000000 2.00
  [2,] 1.00 1.333333  0.6666667 1.333333  0.6666667 0.50
  [3,] 0.20 0.250000  2.0000000 1.250000 10.0000000 8.00
  [4,] 0.50 1.000000  0.1000000 2.000000  0.2000000 0.10
  [5,] 0.60 0.600000  0.7500000 1.000000  1.2500000 1.25
```

If the data was in a dataframe and not a matrix, then you can use array manipulations:

eg. let us assume the matrix above to be `A=as.data.frame(A)` Then

```
  combn(A,2,function(x)x[,1,]/x[,2,])
      [,1]     [,2]       [,3]     [,4]       [,5] [,6]
[1,] 1.25 5.000000 10.0000000 4.000000  8.0000000 2.00
[2,] 1.00 1.333333  0.6666667 1.333333  0.6666667 0.50
[3,] 0.20 0.250000  2.0000000 1.250000 10.0000000 8.00
[4,] 0.50 1.000000  0.1000000 2.000000  0.2000000 0.10
[5,] 0.60 0.600000  0.7500000 1.000000  1.2500000 1.25
```

You can still modify the code the way you want.This is just a rough idea. Hope it helps

Comment: combn(**4,2**,function(x) A[,x[1]]/A[,x[2]]) - Thank you for a prompt reply. To confirm, what exactly does 4 and 2  represent here. My matrix is 716*274, so I will have to adjust those numbers i believe

Comment: 4 is the number of variables you have.. and 2 is the number of elements to choose from 4. you are choosing 2 elements.. I could also have stated `combn(ncol(A),2,....)`

Comment: `combn` stands for combinations.. you have `x1,x2,x3,x4`. You have to choose only two: `x1 &x2, x1&x3..etc` You are combining 2 out of the four variables that you have. play with the function `combn` eg `combn(4,2)` and see what you get. you can also do `combn(4,2,simplify=FALSE)` If the simplified one is unclear

Answer (score 1):

```
dat <- structure(list(X1 = c(10L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L), X2 = c(8L, 4L, 10L, 
2L, 5L), X3 = c(2L, 3L, 8L, 1L, 5L), X4 = c(1L, 6L, 1L, 10L, 
4L)), .Names = c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

When you use apply on a row-wise basis, you need to transpose the result to get values by row:

```
t( # this is the last function to execute, we will need to convert to row basis
  apply(dat, 1, # loop over rows, single row at a time
   function( r){ apply( combn(r,2), 2,  # now loop over columns of `combn` result
                                   function(x) x[[1]]/x[[2]]) }))
     [,1]     [,2]       [,3]     [,4]       [,5] [,6]
[1,] 1.25 5.000000 10.0000000 4.000000  8.0000000 2.00
[2,] 1.00 1.333333  0.6666667 1.333333  0.6666667 0.50
[3,] 0.20 0.250000  2.0000000 1.250000 10.0000000 8.00
[4,] 0.50 1.000000  0.1000000 2.000000  0.2000000 0.10
[5,] 0.60 0.600000  0.7500000 1.000000  1.2500000 1.25
```